# Place content on facebook

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to place any elements on a facebook page outside the application space? I would like to place a box below the tab menu or at the right next to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this.  Facebook will only allow you to use the space allocated in the Facebook Applications.